# Assign default return value in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I recently switched to Eclipse for Java and am adjusting to the shortcuts, autocompletes and so on.

I am missing a very comfortable option to assign default values when using a function

[image]

Is there a similar option in Eclipse to create a variable if the function has a return type?

Comment: If the function has a return type but no return statement then you can use the `Add return statement` quick fix (mouse over function's name) to automatically return the last statement. Similarly another quick fix automatically changes function's return type if it finds a `return` statement in a void function. I am not aware of any other shortcut; that could be an interesting feature request for the JDT.

Comment: I can not implement your suggestion. Hovering over the function only gives the function name in the popup window

Comment: Eclipse IDE should show you an error with a red marker on the left. If hovering the function shows nothing you can click directly on the marker to display available fixes. Note: regarding the quick fix that updates function's return type I think that you have to hover the return statement.

Comment: Why should there be an error? It is not necessary to assign a return value to a function I called. Sometimes a yellow lightbulb pops up with suggestions (e.g. 'remove unused import'). I was hoping there is a suggestion for variable creation.

Comment: The two features I mentionned are [quick fixes](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-quickfix-assist.htm), which means that they are only triggered by an error (as opposed to [quick assists](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-quickfix-assist.htm) that are triggered upon selected element).

Comment: The `Add return statement` quickfix is triggered when a function has a return type but not return statement. The `Change return type` quickfix is triggered when a function has a return statement but no return type. Sadly, I don't think there are any other shortcut close to what you want but you can create a ticket in JDT's Bugzilla to ask the team to create them.